# How to make app work on second use in emulator

Tags: android, emulation, mobile-application

When running the app in android studio the first time it asks for permission and continues normally but when I run it the second time it just reports an error and stops. The error reported has to do with permissions to the image gallery but cannot understand why since it works the first time and permissions granted. When running app on mobile it works every time. Any help or suggestions will do. Thanks.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, you should also post you code with question so others can outline any errors or give suggestions.

Comment: add code and image this error please